# how to get lat lng on moving objects

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have google map on a webpage which shows user location on it. It asks user's permission to grab its location and then loads map and show a marker there. It works well obviously when you are siting in a room and open it. But what if I am using mobile and walking on the road or sitting in a bus. How to update my position on map then? If you happen to see on google map in a bus, it shows your position (marker) moving along the bus. So how can we get user location on a still map without refreshing page and update its location along the bus?

Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change the method you're using to have the browser access the user's location from `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` to `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition`. This will   let you monitor their location as it changes instead of just getting it once.

Google probably would have helped you find this simply enough.

[Real time GPS Tracker on JUST HTML / JS and Google Maps to be run on a handphone? Is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305225/real-time-gps-tracker-on-just-html-js-and-google-maps-to-be-run-on-a-handphone)