# real time gps reall needs database?

Tags: javascript, gps, real-time

I'm working on a project that involves real time tracking. I'm using `html5 geolocation API` and I'm stuck where users should locate others. Mine is not storing the lat,lng of the user in a database. Now my question is can I continue my project without database?

Comment: You can try using sockets https://www.npmjs.com/package/gps-tracking-maps-socket-io. I don't know whether its feasible for your project requirement

Comment: is there a way that doesn't involved third party apps/software?

Comment: You can use your own implementation of sockets, you can use the package as ref and check the code to understand how it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. When you receive the GPS data, you could directly send it to all recipients. Therefore, you dont have to store it in a database. To be able to create channels with clients that stay open over a longer time, HTTP wont work, you will have to use WebSockets instead. A famous implementatoon for nodejs is https://socket.io

Comment: thanks for the answer 1 more question is there alternative solution besides Websockets i saw this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305225/ using server-side scripting is it possible i'd like to avoid using your suggestion seems hard kinda sucks at programming :/

Comment: @jason that only works if you wanna see your own position.